# Simple gORM unit testing but failed when testing multiple case using subtest

Tags: go, testing, go-gorm

I am setting a simple unit test for my gORM function like this.

```golang
func (o *OrderStorage) FindByID(ID uint) (*Order, error) {
    var order Order
    result := o.db.First(&order, ID)

    if result.Error != nil {
        return nil, result.Error
    }

    return &order, nil
}

func testOrderStorage_FindByID(o OrderService) func(t *testing.T) {
    return func(t *testing.T) {
        type args struct {
            ID uint
        }
        tests := []struct {
            name string
            args args
        }{
            {
                name: "2nd Order",
                args: args{
                    ID: 2,
                },
            },
            // {
            //  name: "3rd Order",
            //  args: args{
            //      ID: 3,
            //  },
            // },
            // {
            //  name: "1st Order",
            //  args: args{
            //      ID: 1,
            //  },
            // },
        }
        for _, tt := range tests {
            tt := tt
            t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
                got, err := o.FindByID(tt.args.ID)
                if err != nil {
                    t.Errorf("OrderStorage.FindByID() error = %v ID %d", err, tt.args.ID)
                    return
                }
                t.Logf("OrderStorage.FindByID() result = %+v ID = %d", *got, tt.args.ID)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

You guys can see that I have 3 test cases. If I test them one by one, they all work correctly. But if I uncomment all of them then run the test in one time, the first test case will be passed but the rest of them will be failed. The gorm fail logs here:

```
2022/01/29 12:55:50 /home/pc/backend/repository/order/order.go:28 record not found
[0.780ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "test_orders" WHERE "test_orders"."id" = 2 AND "test_orders"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "test_orders"."id" = 3 ORDER BY "test_orders"."id","test_orders"."id" LIMIT 1
```

I have no idea why the query of the second test case have the `WHERE "test_orders"."id" = 2` which is the ID from the first case.

Can anybody explain that to me? Thanks!

Comment: the `tt := tt` line is weird. could please confirm that the issue still exists without this line?

Comment: you have in `where` clause `id=2 and id=3`. It will return 0 rows.

Comment: the `tt :=tt` is not cause of the issue, even I remove them the issue still occur.

`you have in where clause id=2 and id=3. It will return 0 rows.` -> Yep, but I wonder why this SQL command appear? What is the root cause? It seems like being cache from the first SQL command :/